# Apply text color one particular tab only in a QTabWidget via stylesheet

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to set the text color of a particular tab in the tab bar of a QTabWidget.
This particular tab may be present at any index(not necessarily first, last or mid, selected or nonselected). For eg: text color of 17th tab in a QTabWidget containing 30 tabs needs to be green. 
How can I achieve the same with stylesheet(not with setTabTextColor API)?
In a stylesheet, we can set the text color of all tabs, or first, last or mid tab. But how to set the text color of a random tab via stylesheet is the question.

Comment: With QSS you cannot set the color for a specific index, only for the references: current, first, last, etc. Why don't you want to use setTabTextColor? since that is the right solution.

Comment: That's because setTabTextColor() is not imposing the text color on my desired tab as there is a stylesheet already applied by the parent application(not under my control) where QTabBar::tab { color: white;} is already applied. I want to overwrite this. setTabTextColor() doesn't overwrite the above applied style. Only way to do so is using tabBar()->setStyleSheet("QTabBar::tab::? { color: green;}"); Hence the question.

Comment: try with: `a.setStyle("fusion")`

Comment: Do you mean something like:  tabWidget->tabBar()->setStyleSheet("fusion"); tabWidget->tabBar()->setTabTextColor(index,textColor); ??

Comment: No, in main.cpp `QApplication a(argc, argv); a.setStyle("fusion");`

Comment: Sorry, it didn't work. Still the style of parent application is taking effect.

Comment: If you want help then provide a [mre], you should also mention in your question the reason why you think you should not use setTabTextColor

Comment: Why don't you set the color "white" also with setTabTextColor? If you do, I think the QSS would not interfere

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend giving your target QTabWidget an object name and using the ID selector to target it specifically. For reference please see the docs on different seelctor types at https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types.

You can set the object name using this property: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#objectName-prop

Answer (score 0):

1. Subclass from `QTabWidget` (just for override its `QTabBar`);
2. Subclass from `QTabBar` and override `paintEvent()`.
3. In `QTabWidget` subclass sets our new tabbar in constructor:

```
setTabBar(new MyTabBar(this));
```

4. Then, here some example code of `QTabBar` subclass:

**.h file** - make tabs text transparent:

```
explicit MyTabBar(QWidget *parent = nullptr) : QTabBar(parent)
{ 
    setStyleSheet("MyTabBar::tab { color: rgba(0,0,0,0) }"); 
}
```

**.cpp file** - painter magic:

```
void MyTabBar::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    QTabBar::paintEvent(event);

    QPainter painter(this);

    for(auto i = 0; i < count(); i++)
    {
        painter.setPen(QColor(YOUR, RANDOM, VALUES));
        painter.drawText(tabRect(i), Qt::AlignHCenter | Qt::AlignVCenter, tabText(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't quite work, I see a black shadow for tabs that aren't selected: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFrke.png. It doesn't seem like the `setStyleSheet` does anything.

Comment: https://ibb.co/G3QFRnd it works. Are you sure you are using rgba? Maybe you set new app stylesheet AFTER creating tabbar?

Comment: Your solution is highly dependent on the style, I ask you to indicate what you get when executing `qDebug() << a.style()->metaObject().className();`

Comment: @eyllanesc what do you want to say? It can be answer? Can. It works? Works. Author can't change root app style so if you can tell another solution - please, I am very interesting in it.